# Why does the coffeescript transpiler call the wrapper function with 'call'?

Tags: coffeescript

Coffeescript transpiles this

```
a = 1
doStuff(a)
```

to this

```
(function() {
  var a;    
  a = 1;    
  doStuff(a);    
}).call(this);
```

I know you can avoid declaring global variables by wrapping your code in an anonymous function

```
(function() {
  var a;    
  a = 1;    
  doStuff(a);    
})();
```

But what is the `.call(this)` in the last line for?
Why is it necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there to ensure that `this` refers to the same thing whether or not you ask CoffeeScript to wrap your code in an anonymous function wrapper.

For a 'top-level' script `this` refers to the global object - `window` in a browser - as it does when evaluating a function without an implicitly or explicitly supplied `this` object.  Therefore in most cases the explicitly supplied `this` argument makes no difference; however you could be consuming the compiled JavaScript output in some other way e.g. evaluating it in a non-global context, and so including it prevents surprising behaviour changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what kind of "surprising behaviour changes"? Can you give me an examlple?

Comment: @a.dorosty if (1) `this` isn't the global object where your script is evaluated and (2) you access the `this` object, e.g. to export some properties, then CoffeeScript not including the `.call(this)` would result in different behaviour (the `this` object meaning something different) than JavaScript, or CoffeeScript when run with the --bare option.